# TexMaker build different document

Tags: texmaker

i have a document in which each chapter gets included as a own tex document.
If i edit one sub tex document and press the run button it runs the current document and not the main document.
I want to create a shortcut which automatically runs pdflatex and view pdf on the main document.

How do i do that?

Comment: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION31

Answer (score 1):

In TexMaker, open your main document (the one that includes all the others), then choose Options/Make Current File the Master (or similar; I have the German version, so I do not know the exact text of the menu item ...).
After that, compiling always starts with the main document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you could show a screen shot -- a German version will do also!